# How can I do a dynamic GARCH model using extended Kalman filter in R?

Tags: r, modeling, garch, dynamic

Today I was reading an [article](https://research.aston.ac.uk/portal/files/240393/AURA_2_unmarked_Energy_demand_and_price_forecasting_using_wavelet_transform_and_adaptive_forecasting_models.pdf) quoted [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/can-i-do-a-garch-model-to-forecast-a-time-series), in this article is proposed an adaptive (dynamic) Garch model. How can I do it in R? The use of extended Kalman filter or particle filter is indifferent. I usually use `rugarch` or `rmgarch` for Garch models. Can I do it with this packages or I need some others? 
Thanks

Comment: You need other packages because neither of those do models in state-space. There are a few packages in r for Kalman filter but I don't know if they allowed to model the variance as a garch process, my guess is not. Take a look at the packages `dlm` and `KFAS`